# Upgrading to jQuery UI 1.12 broke slide() and drop() effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Quoting the **[Upgrade Guide](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2016/03/jquery-ui-1-12-0-release-candidate-1/)**:

> Effects overhaul: The effects API has received a major overhaul,
>   introducing many new APIs and rewriting effects to use CSS clip for
>   smoother and less error-prone animations. In addition, the transfer
>   effect has been replaced with a .transfer() method.

I have a holder div with a "slide div" within it. It seems that 1.12 has caused the slide/drop effect to initially `display: none`, then `clip`? The result is a choppy, blinky mess that in no way resembles a slide.

I've been trying to work around this a while. I'm hoping someone's encountered this issue and solved it somehow. It happens for any element on the page, as well. I thought it was a conflict with other CSS or JS, but I disabled what I could and still nothing.

This bug occurs in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you try to create a demo? in using snippet or a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue you posted. I setup the Effect Demo using jQuery 2.2.3 and jQuery UI 1.12.0-rc.1, seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vrgosgca/

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Effect</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="drop">Drop</option>
  <option value="explode">Explode</option>
  <option value="fade">Fade</option>
  <option value="fold">Fold</option>
  <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
  <option value="puff">Puff</option>
  <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
  <option value="scale">Scale</option>
  <option value="shake">Shake</option>
  <option value="size">Size</option>
  <option value="slide">Slide</option>
  <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
</select>

<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
```

**jQuery UI**

```
$(function() {
  // run the currently selected effect
  function runEffect() {
    // get effect type from
    var selectedEffect = $("#effectTypes").val();

    // most effect types need no options passed by default
    var options = {};
    // some effects have required parameters
    if (selectedEffect === "scale") {
      options = {
        percent: 0
      };
    } else if (selectedEffect === "transfer") {
      options = {
        to: "#button",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"
      };
    } else if (selectedEffect === "size") {
      options = {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 60
        }
      };
    }

    // run the effect
    $("#effect").effect(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback);
  };

  // callback function to bring a hidden box back
  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#effect").removeAttr("style").hide().fadeIn();
    }, 1000);
  };

  // set effect from select menu value
  $("#button").click(function() {
    runEffect();
    return false;
  });
});
```

The Slide action appears smooth. I picked this example as it closely lined up with your description. Since you did not include an example of the code you're using, I cannot say why yours is "choppy".

At first, I thought you meant `.slider()`. In the future, always include example code.

Comment: It's likely internal within my system, it's not as if JQ UI put out a buggy release candidate. My hope is that someone who encountered it and fixed it will have some insight, so I'll take the rep hit.

Comment: Why didn't you specify that in your post? What spechs are you using? Browser? Did you post to any spots?

Comment: I admit to negligence only in that I didn't provide the browsers I tested in; embarrassingly, that I didn't even test in anything but Chrome. Still, the problem persists in all browsers. The question has been updated.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What steps does someone need to take to replicate the issue?

Comment: Windows, does that really matter here? The steps would be to install 1.12 in their working application, see the functionality's broken, and move on from there. If I made this in a clean fiddle, there's a good chance it'd work as well as yours did. This all takes place in a complex system of scripts and CSS, which I tried to disable most of, and even as barebones as I could go would still leave the issue in.

Comment: @VaelVictus you previously mentioned it was an issue *nternal within my system, it's not as if JQ UI put out a buggy release candidate*, so I was trying to see what about your system is causing the animation to be choppy. Now you're suggesting that it's not internal, not a browser issue, and also not a bug in the jQuery UI code. It sounds like now, you are blaming the complexity of your scripts yet have provided no example code or any way for anyone on SO to assist you. So someone like myself, that wants to help, can't do so.

Comment: There is a way for someone on SO to assist me: if they upgraded and had a malfunction similar to how I describe, they manage to fix it, and they post here. (or at least offer insight) I imagine people will slowly begin to upgrade to 1.12 and have these effects break when they upgrade, so I'll leave the question around for such cases. I personally have no urgency to update to 1.12 from 1.11, so I've just reverted and am carrying on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by global CSS that used translatez() to circumvent a visual glitch in Chrome. It was placed outside of the standard CSS file.

```
#main-content * {
  webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
}
```

Per the jQuery UI Team:

> The effects API has received a major overhaul, introducing many new
>   APIs and rewriting effects to use CSS clip for smoother and less
>   error-prone animations.

This affected all child divs within the main-content and interfered with the animation now using `clip`. Thankfully, the glitch was because of the old, sometimes problematic effects, so nothing was lost by removing such lines.

**If you are using translatez() to circumvent the Chrome visual glitch and receiving this error, you can now safely remove the transform.**